# how to map key value pairs in nifi?

Tags: python, json

I have incoming data like the below mentioned:

**Input** :

```json
{
  "results": {
    "columns": [
      [
        "id",
        "name",
        "type"
      ],
      [
        "id",
        "name",
        "type"
      ],
      [
        "id",
        "name",
        "type"
      ]
    ],
    "rows": [
      [
        "D01",
        "vm01",
        "vms"
      ],
      [
        "D02",
        "vm02",
        "vms"
      ],
      [
        "D03",
        "vm03",
        "vms"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

The columns are the keys and rows are the values and are expected as key-value pairs

**Expected output** :

```json
[
  {
    "id": "D01",
    "name": "vm01",
    "type": "vms"
  },
  {
    "id": "D02",
    "name": "vm02",
    "type": "vms"
  },
  {
    "id": "D03",
    "name": "vm03",
    "type": "vms"
  }
]
```

Comment: Dear Pandu, welcome to SO. My answer has been updated. But it would be best if you did not change your question. Please ask a new question next time.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering the question using its original `python` tag...)

If you can get a sequence of pairs like `[("id", "D01"), ("name", "vm01"), ("type", "vms")]`, you can create the desired `dict` value:

```
>>> dict([("id", "D01"), ("name", "vm01"), ("type", "vms")])
{ "id": "D01", "name": "vm01", "type": "vms" }
```

You can get such lists by mapping `zip` over each corresponding pair of columns and rows.

```
>>> [dict(t) for t in map(zip, x['data']['rows'], x['data']['columns'])]
[{'D01': 'id', 'vm01': 'name', 'vms': 'type'}, {'D02': 'id', 'vm02': 'name', 'vms': 'type'}, {'D03': 'id', 'vm03': 'name', 'vms': 'type'}]
```

Comment: I would add that if the import were a string, then using `loads` from the `json` module would be the first step. Also switch the order of `'rows'` and `'columns'` - your result has the keys and values switched. Nice work with the one liner - I keep forgetting about `map`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "columns": {
          "*": {
            "@2,rows": { //go two levels up the tree to get the values of the rows array
              "*": {
                "@(0,[&1])": "[#2].@(3,[&2])" //match arrays from their original positions
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi, the question changed and I edited your solution with the new updated question.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer with previews `jolt` tag.**

You can use the following JOLT spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "rows": {
          "*": {
            "*": "[&1].@(3,columns[&1][&])"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**How does it work?**

Just go to the `rows` items level and get all values with `*` use the following code as the place of the keys

```json
[&1].@(3,columns[&1][&])
```

**`[&1]`**: Index of the `rows` items (array of `rows`). `0, 1, 2`

**`[&]`**: Index of the `rows` items values (arrays of `rows` array). `0, 1, 2`

**`@(3,columns)`**: Value of `columns`. `[[], [], []]`

**`@(3,columns[&1])`**: Values of `columns` items. `[], [], []`

**`@(3,columns[&1][&])`**: Values of `columns` items field. `id, name, type`